# Inner part of donut chart suddenly not "fitting"

Tags: highcharts

I haven't made any changes to the .js code I use for the donut chart we use on our website (http://www.innovatorfunds.com/fund.php).  However, when I went to the site today the pie chart is busted.  Specifically, the inner pie chart doesn't "fit" anymore.  It's smaller than it should be and not centered.  Any wisdom?

Comment: Out of curiosity are you using a local highcharts library on your server or using the HighCharts hosted one? Version 3.0 was released today so it is possible if you are using the HighCharts hosted js file you are now on v3.

Answer (score 0):

Set in `plotOptions.pie` or in each `series` object:

```
series: [{
    data: [...],
    center: ['50%','50%']
}, {
    data: [...],
    center: ['50%','50%']
}]
```